# Probability of subsets

Tags: probability

I have a problem, since I don't know how to solve the following exercise:

If $C_1$ and $C_2$ are subsets of the sample space, show that
$P(C_1 \cap C_2)\leq P(C_1) \leq P(C_1 \cup C_2) \leq P(C_1)+P(C_2)$

I thought about saying, that 
$C_1 \cap C_2  \leq C_1$, then by a theorem, which says "If $C_1$ is contained in $C_2$, then $P(C_1)\leq P(C_2)$, so I am thinking that I can use this theorem, but I don't think it is enough to just say that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is enough. Side note: Use $\subseteq$ for inclusion rather than $\leq $.

Comment: Okay, so I can split it up in three parts.  First part is $P(C_1\cap C_2 ) \leq P(C_1)$. So I can say that $C_1 \cap C_2 \subseteq C_1$ and from the theorem I mentioned, then I can take the probability of the subsets, such that $P(C_1 \cap C_2) \leq P(C_1)$. The same is the case for $P(C_1) \leq P(C_1 \cup C_2)$ and the same case for $P(C_1 \cup C_2) \leq P(C_1)+P(C_2)$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three parts. Here is the first:

If some element $c$ is contained in $C_1 \cap C_2$, then it must be contained in $C_1$. As $C_1 \cap C_2 \subseteq C_1$, we use your theorem to justify that $P(C_1 \cap C_2) \leq P(C_1)$.

You can take it from here.

Comment: Then I can say that c is contained in $C_1$, then it must be contained in $C_1 \cup C_2$ as well right? I'm just asking to be sure.

Comment: Exactly. This reasoning works for all three parts.

Comment: Okay, now I get it. Thanks a lot!